# How does token endpoint knows about user authenticated during authorization code generation

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth

Rfc6749 states that after getting an authorization code, we can exchange this code against an accessToken.

I'm wondering how does the authorization server knows the identity of the person who originally received the code ?
I cannot see in the spec that the code is associated with the user authenticated during the step "getting the code"

Answer (score 2):

The combination of redirect_url and code provides information about who. This is then used to lookup the transaction in progress. This is implementation-specific on how these items are used to lookup the original authorization request.

In the simplest view, the code is used to request an access token for an already approved authorization request. Only a registered URL (endpoint) receives the code, which provides for the secrecy/security of the generated tokens.